# What is the most concise form of an immutable data class in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, properties, immutability

I have an `enum State` and a `class Neighborhood` that uses them as data.  I'm new to C#, so I'm not sure if this is idiomatic or could be more concise (or just plain wrong).

```
public enum State : byte
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2
}

public class Neighborhood
{

    private State _left, _center, _right;

    public Neighborhood(State left, State center, State right)
    {
        _left = left;
        _center = center;
        _right = right;
    }

    public State left { get { return _left; } }

    public State center { get { return _center; } }

    public State right { get { return _right; } }
}
```

**Is there a shorter or more idiomatic way to do this?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is nothing wrong with the code. Questions asking about review or improvements to code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that unless the fields are marked with `readonly`, your class is not truly immutable.

Comment: spot on. but i supose that Neighborhood could be a struct.

Comment: Well, there *is* something wrong with the code, with all the properties returning the value of `_left`... :)

Comment: @jlahd: hah! yes, good point. But the OP isn't complaining about any problems related to that, so that _must_ have been on purpose. ;)

Comment: @PeterDuniho, how do I properly migrate the question to CodeReview?  When that happens, can you please add your `readonly` idea as an answer?  I've never seen that construct before.

Comment: I think that migration requires moderator intervention (i.e. a flag). Of course, you can always do it manually, simply by copy/pasting the question to the other site and deleting the question here. See [readonly (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) for information on how to use the `readonly` keyword and what it does.

Comment: @kdbanman I don't think this is the greatest post to migrate over to CR. Code Review works best for when you have real working code from an actual project that you want to have feedback on any and all aspects of the code. This question is really just asking "what's the best practice regarding X?", which is explicitly off-topic on CR (see [the help center](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @Mat'sMug, alright, then I'll leave this one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most *concise* way of writing it, but there are a number of differences between using `readonly` backing fields and `private set` auto-properties:

- `private set` implies that the class implementation can alter the value of the property.
- `readonly` backing field can only be initialized from the constructor; the class implementation cannot alter its value.
- `readonly` backing field better communicates the *intent*, if that intent is to make something *immutable*.
- backing fields with a `_namingConvention` make the `this` qualifier redundant.
- get-only property with a `readonly` backing field is inherently thread-safe; more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975677/1188513).

```
public class Neighborhood
{
    public Neighborhood(State left, State center, State right)
    {
        _left = left;
        _center = center;
        _right = right;
    }

    private readonly State _left;
    public State Left { get { return _left; } }

    private readonly State _center;
    public State Center { get { return _center; } }

    private readonly State _right;
    public State Right { get { return _right; } }
}
```

Comment: I guess my class wasn't correct (immutable) after all.  I prioritize clarity and correctness above concision, so this is *excellent*.

Comment: Just recognized something - should `Neighborhood` be [sealed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw) as well? Or are read only field safe for subclasses too?

Comment: Not sure I see how, but if [Jon Skeet says subclassing can break immutability](http://stackoverflow.com/a/268287/1188513), I believe him. Rule of thumb though, is to never seal a class, unless you have very good reasons to do so.

Comment: Ok.  One more thing - why not shorten each data field to `public  readonly State Left;`, and do `Left = left; ` in the constructor?  Not sure if that's clear..

Comment: You sure that would compile?

Comment: @kdbanman [don't expose public fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/480637/1188513)

Comment: That rule is for the sake of maintainability.  I could change a public field to a public property without breaking any dependent code, could I not?

Comment: @kdbanman http://stackoverflow.com/a/480638/1188513. and the rule is also about OOP best practices.

Comment: Languages like Python and C# allow classes to have properties with getters and setters, but are accessed and mutated as normal public fields.  EX: `myInstance.someField = 42;`.  In Java, you're *definitely* setting a field.  Bad.  But in Python or C#, you could be using a setter under the hood.  So if one can easily change from a public field to a public getter **without breaking dependent code**, then isn't the "no public fields" rule not so hard-and-fast?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82782/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-kdbanman).

Comment: Woop, you're right.  I just found [relevant information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0).  Such a switch messes with serialization, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum State : byte
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 1,
    two = 2
}

public class Neighborhood
{
    public Neighborhood(State left, State center, State right)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Center = center;
        this.Right = right;
    }

    public State Left { get; private set; }

    public State Center { get; private set; }

    public State Right { get; private set; }
}
```