# Which relation between Type.GetProperty and a readonly field

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got the following class:

```
public sealed class ImmutableObject {

         public readonly int ic;

         public ImmutableObject(int value) {
             ic = value;
         }
}
```

Then I created a method that tries to obtain reflection informations by this class:

```
public static void infosByImmutableObject() {
         ImmutableObject iobj = new ImmutableObject(1);

         Console.WriteLine(iobj.ic);

         Type typeIobj = iobj.GetType();

         PropertyInfo infos = typeIobj.GetProperty("ic");

}
```

I can't understand why, although `ic` is `public`, `infos` remains `null`, and if I try with `Type.GetProperties` the result array has zero elements. I noticed that, without the `readonly` modifier, `GetProperties("ic")` returns. How a public field is seen by `GetProperty(`) when the `readonly` is present?

Comment: `ic` is not a property, it's a field. You should use GetField or GetFields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ic` is not a property, it's a field. You should use `GetField` or `GetFields` to retrieve a `FieldInfo` object for it:

```
FieldInfo infos = typeIobj.GetField("ic");
Debug.Assert(infos!=null);
```

Fields and properties are different types of members in .NET. In general, properties are considered a part of a class's interface while fields are considered part of its implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't aware of this distinction. For duty I attach this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7975677/3544562)

Comment: For extra fun, see what happens if you try to set a `readonly` field through reflection.